# One liner to extract values within list of dictionaries into multiple variables

Tags: python

Say we have a list of similarly structured dictionaries, for example:

```
lst_of_dcts = [
    {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4,
    },
    ...
    {
        'a': 10,
        'b': 11,
        'c': 12,
        'd': 13,
    },
    {
        'a': 14,
        'b': 15,
        'c': 16,
        'd': 17,
    }
]
```

I want to extract lists of keys, for example

```
as = [d['a'] for d in lst_of_dcts]
bs = [d['b'] for d in lst_of_dcts]
cs = [d['c'] for d in lst_of_dcts]
```

For example, `as` == `[1, ..., 10, 14]`

Is there a cleaner way to do this, perhaps in one line, that saves me iterating over the list of dictionaries multiple times.

Comment: In one line: `a, b, c = [[dct[key] for dct in lst_of_dcts] for key in 'abc']`, but it still requires multiple iterations. If you want to get them in one iteration, it will become slower because of the slow method search (unless future Python can recognize that we are doing `list.append` and inline them).

Comment: `as = [d['a'] for d in lst_of_dcts]` is invalid syntax, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as a one liner:

`a,b,c = list(map(list, zip(*[(d['a'], d['b'], d['c']) for d in lst_of_dcts])))`

However, you sacrifice 1. readability, and 2. speed.

```
import numpy as np
import time

n_iter = 10000
times = []
for _ in range(n_iter):
    t0 = time.time()
    a,b,c = list(map(list, zip(*[(d['a'], d['b'], d['c']) for d in lst_of_dcts])))
    times.append(time.time() - t0)
print(np.mean(times))

times = []
for _ in range(n_iter):
    t0 = time.time()
    a =[d['a'] for d in lst_of_dcts]
    b =[d['b'] for d in lst_of_dcts]
    c =[d['c'] for d in lst_of_dcts]
    times.append(time.time() - t0)
print(np.mean(times))
```

Times:

```
2.23792e-06s
1.68469e-06s
```

Comment: The way the input data is given in the original question (note the ellipsis) implies that the list may contain more than three dictionaries. Therefore I suggest that the 3-variable approach really doesn't make much sense

Comment: @OldBill The number of dictionaries is not an influencing factor here. The two solutions given here can work normally, because only the values corresponding to three keys are taken here.

Comment: @MechanicPig I think you'll find that the dictionaries have 4 keys

Comment: @OldBill But OP did not say to take all.

Comment: @MechanicPig OK - I concede. This is a fantastic answer and I'm very tempted to upvote it. I will of course remove my ridiculous answer

Answer (score 0):

Just [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) your list of objects.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce

lst_of_dcts = [
    {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': 3,
        'd': 4,
    },
    {
        'a': 10,
        'b': 11,
        'c': 12,
        'd': 13,
    },
    {
        'a': 14,
        'b': 15,
        'c': 16,
        'd': 17,
    }
]

def reducer(result, current):
    for k, v in current.items():
        result[k].append(v)
    return result

result = reduce(reducer, lst_of_dcts, defaultdict(list))

print(result)
```

Here you automatically catch all the keys without introducing those variables, so you solve the common case problem.

[Working example at repl.it](https://replit.com/@f0t0n/reducelist#main.py)